# AndroidManifest BroadcastReceiver for external SDK

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I am trying to integrate Estimote bluetooth low energy beacons into an existing (big) Android 12 application. The problem is that the Manifest merger fails:

```
Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.estimote.proximity_sdk.api.TriggerBroadcastReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.
```

From the SDK I understood that they implemented the Android BroadcastReceiver. So I tried to include the following into my AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver
     android:name="android.content.BroadcastReceiver"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="false" >
</receiver>
```

This did not work and gives me still the same error. I failed to explicitly defined the class from the SDK. I tried:

```
<receiver
     android:name="com.estimote.proximity_sdk.api.TriggerBroadcastReceiver"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="false" >
</receiver>
```

But I get: `Unresolved class 'TriggerBroadcastReceiver'`

I don't really understand why it is not sufficient to define the Android BroadcastReceiver and how I can define a receiver for the class `TriggerBroadcastReceiver` from the SDK.

Any ideas, hints, explanations are very much appreciated!

Comment: What version of the Estimote SDK are you using? I tried to include what seems to be the latest, `1.0.7`, and Gradle fails to even find all its transient dependencies, much less get to the manifest merge stage. But judging by its manifest which targets API 28, this version is also quite old, and doesn't include the `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permisison needed to target API 31 / Android 12. Their website barely mentions BLE -- they are pushing hard on UWB beacons these days though it seems their new UWB beacons do still support BLE.

Comment: I realized I needed to add `jcenter()` to get the other dependencies. After that, I was able to replicate your error. However for me, adding the `TriggerBroadcastReceiver` to the app manifest did successfully replace the receiver specified by the SDK's manifest. Additionally, I added the missing `intent-filter` for `<action android:name="com.estimote.proximity_trigger" />`. I don't have any Estimote beacons to test with, but that seems to at least merge to the desired result. After this, you might need to add `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` and then request it at runtime, or target API 30.

Comment: Yes, jcenter() is needed Could you please, maybe also as an answer, write the receiver declaration for the app Manifest that is working for you? I still get syntax errors and don't know how to put it there.

Comment: I think I got it, I hope. So if you like, put your comment in an answer that I can accept it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.0.7 of the Estimote SDK does not seem to support Android API level 31. Looks like it's stuck at 26! Luckily there are some ways to massage the manifest into what is hopefully needed.

First, add to your manifest's `application` element:

```xml
    <receiver android:name="com.estimote.proximity_sdk.api.TriggerBroadcastReceiver" 
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.estimote.proximity_trigger" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

If you can Context Menu > "Go to Declaration" for the above `TriggerBroadcastReceiver` then it ought to be wired up correctly. I was unable to replicate your finding of `Unresolved class 'TriggerBroadcastReceiver'`.  So hopefully that resolves your immediate problem. But after that, there is a bit more you'll likely need to allow BLE scanning to proceed.

Assuming your min SDK version is 30 or less, to override Estimote's unqualified use of the following permissions, you can add:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
```

More importantly, I believe you will need to add `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission locations to your manifest, which are needed when scanning on API 31 or greater:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

In the app code, you will then need to request `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions. (Fine location because Beacons do confer physical location!) If I understand correctly, the Estimote SDK allows scanning to persist in the background via a foreground service, so you won't need to mess with `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`.

Alternatively, you could target API 30 in your app, which does not enforce the `exported` receiver attribute rule, and doesn't make use of `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` for BLE scanning.

Caveat: I am unable to test because I'm not an Estimote user. But at least my app builds and runs.

---

[Bluetooth permissions: Target Android 12 or higher](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#declare-android12-or-higher)